# ASP.net MVC MembershipProvider for MySQL on Existing tables

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

**Language/Technical Bits**

- ASP.net MVC 4 written in VB & razor. (Created from Internet Template)
- MySQL 5.5
- Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web (Soon to be upgraded to Professional)

**Requirement**

I need to implement Membership and Roles into my ASP.net MVC 4 application. I have an existing MySQL database with a Users table that I would prefer to utilise for this purpose.

However, due to time constraints and because I am relatively new to ASP.net MVC development, I would like to do this with as little technical coding or re-writing as possible.

Here is the main part of the create statement for the existing users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
    `User_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Company_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Surname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `Password_Salt` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `Status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `Created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `Modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`User_ID`))
```

Whilst I have some flexibility and can add or remove some of the fields from the Users table, the User_ID and Company_ID fields are extremely important and must remain as they are used as foreign keys in at least a half dozen other tables.

I also do not want to have to use the Username field, instead I want to have all account logins use the Email field.

**State of play at present**

At the moment, I have been able to successfully setup and test the standard MySQLMembershipProvider using its default set of autogenerated tables...

```
my_aspnet_applications
my_aspnet_membership
my_aspnet_profiles
my_aspnet_roles
my_aspnet_schemaversion
my_aspnet_sessioncleanup
my_aspnet_sessions
my_aspnet_users
my_aspnet_usersinroles
```

In an ideal world I would prefer to replace the my_aspnet_users table (removing all of the other tables in the process) and utilise my own Users table (and roles table structure). I understand however that this involves writing a custom MembershipProvider and this is something I would rather avoid for the moment, I need something quick and something that doesn't involve re-inventing the wheel.

For the time being, I would settle for a link between the default Membership users table and my own table through the use of a key.

**The Questions**

1. What is the best way to create the link between my_aspnet_users and Users?
2. How do I restrict the provider to only use the email address?
3. How would I retreive the First and Last name, as well as Company ID from the Users table depending on who is logged in? (To display the name of the user when logged in instead of their email address, etc)
4. Has anyone found any articles, tutorials or videos which helped them with something similair or the same?

Many thanks in advance for any assistance anyone can provide regarding this, I greatly appreciate it!!!

Comment: Well, I had hoped to find an answer here, because i'm stuck trying to get rid of those tables being generated.